# Does the cloud pattern in the image have a name?

Tags: meteorology

The image was taken about 5 p.m. in January, 2017.

[image]

Comment: Has it been featured at [APOD](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/)? They like pretty meteorological pictures like this.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a variation of a [roll cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcus_cloud#Roll_cloud), where the rolls are smaller in diameter and more numerous.

Answer (score 3):

It could be a horizontal convective roll, also known as a [cloud street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_convective_rolls).